# RxJS: Force already existing Observable start with new value

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

If I have already existing `Observable` like this:

```
Observable.of(0)
  .merge(subject$.map(value => acc => acc + value))
  .scan((acc, fn) => fn(acc));
```

Can I make it start not from `0`, but from `100`? Like it was `Observable.of(100)` from the beginning? I have tried `startWith` operator, but it just adds one value before others, and does not send it through the transformation pipe.

I cannot use any wrapper function to change `of` argument from the beginning.

Maybe, there is some combination? E.g., with `merge` or `mergeMap`?

**RxJS version**: 5.4.0

Comment: Why? This doesn't make much sense. Are you trying to reuse the composed part that's after the `Observable.of(0)`?

Comment: @cartant, yes, some kind of this. I want to make `0` default state and `100` initial state that can be set or can be not set.

Comment: Do you want to reset the accumulation when the initial value changed (start again from the new initial value)? Or do you want to keep the accumulation, and just change its first accumulated value?

Comment: @ZahiC, it should happen before the first subscription, so in common it doesn't mind. But I think, it should reset accumulation

Comment: I added an answer. btw, why do you map the value from subject$ to a function when you can write the function in the scan operator? I kept it in my answer but you can write the exact same behavior much simpler. Let me know if you want me to change it.

Comment: @ZahiC, sorry, I may not be clear. I cannot create observable, it is already exist. E.g. I import it from somewhere in the form I defined in question. So I cannot pass anything to `of` argument.

Comment: OK :) You cannot modify the first value of an existing observable if it's hardcoded. But, you can skip it by skip(1) and send another value to subject$. Does it work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145752/discussion-between-zahic-and-lodin).

Comment: This question is hard to understand. 1) How many values can the first observable emit? (`Observable.of(0)` in the example)
2) What should happen to the value(s) emitted by the first observable if you decide to set the initial state to 100?